# undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.ds') for listView ReactNative

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to display the elements in LISTVIEW in react native

In this section I am trying to populate the data and check for the row similarity 
and set the dataSource.

```js
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
      this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://localHost:3000');
    this.socket.on('Channel1', this.onReceivedMessage);
    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      ds: ['rCode'],
      dataSource: ds

    };
  }
```

Here the rCode is being displayed properly in the listView

```js
  componentDidMount() {
  this.setState({
     dataSource:this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(this.state.ds),
    })

  }
```

Here, i am not able to display newDs in the listView it gives me error

```js
  onReceivedMessage(messages) {
    rcodeSet.add(JSON.stringify(messages.rCode));
    var newDs = [];

    newDs = Array.from(rcodeSet);

    this.setState({
        
        dataSource:this.state.ds.cloneWithRows([...newDs]),
      })
   }
```

error:

```js
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.ds')
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because the context of your `onReceivedMessage` callback is not that of your component instance.

As a result, `this.state` is undefined, because `onReceivedMessage` is executed in the global/window context (ie where `this.state` is not defined), rather than in context of your component instance.

To call `onReceivedMessage` from the context your component instance, try adjusting the code in your component constructor to this:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.socket = SocketIOClient('http://localHost:3000');

    // Wrap the callback with a lambda function, so 
    // that onReceivedMessage is called from the context of your component
    this.socket.on('Channel1', (messages) => this.onReceivedMessage(messages));

    var ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
    this.state = {
      ds: ['rCode'],
      dataSource: ds

    };
  }
```

To better understand the details of function context, and arrow functions,  see [this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Arrow_functions)